# BeautifulSoup - How to find the third consecutive div

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How to find the third consecutive div (not next)

```
x = soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'a'})
x.find_next('div').text
```

I expect `<div id="d">`(third consecutive div after `div id="a"`)

```
<div id="a" class="text" >1</div>
<div id="b" class="text" >2</div>
<div id="c" class="text" >3</div>
<div id="d" class="text" >4</div>
```

Comment: So do you want to find the div relative to the current one, or just the 4th in the parent?

Comment: Relative to the current one (id="a"). In my example I find div id="b" (next). I except the third consecutive div (id="d")

Answer (score 4):

Use `find_all()` instead and use it as a list with an index:

```
.find_all('div')[2]
```

To find a nth next sibling, use `.find_next_siblings()` instead, and select the 3rd element:

```
thirddiv = x.find_next_siblings('div')[2]
```